# components on Gridbag Layout positioning error(Java)?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I am using gridbag layout for the flexible layout of my project but really it is now becoming headache for me ,,after a hard try of nearly 5 hours i am not able to do the correct positionin according to my requirement ,,plz figure it out for me :-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        //frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setFont(f);
        frame.setTitle("Natural Language Processor");

        frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

            // Setting the label for the nlp            
            l = new JLabel("Natural Language Processor");
            l.setFont(f);
            c.weightx = 0.5;
            c.gridx = 0;
            c.gridy = 0;
            c.ipady = 20;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
            frame.add(l, c);

            l1 = new JLabel("English");
            l.setFont(f1);
            c.weightx = 0.0;
            c.weighty = 1.0;
            c.gridy = 1;
            c.gridx = 0;

            //c.ipady = 20;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;

            frame.add(l1, c);
```

[image: output of code]

In the pic above I want the label "English" to be below the "Natural" of "natural Language processor" label instead of centering it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all don't forget to run your Swing code in the EDT by invoking all this code using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Runnable r)`.

There are several ways to do this, which one is the best depends on what else you'll put on the UI. This is one of the shortest ways to do it:

**WAY 1**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TitleTestFrame extends JFrame
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new TitleTestFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public TitleTestFrame()
    {
        super("frame title");

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("This is a centered title.");
        JLabel subtitleLabel = new JLabel("Subtitle");

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.weightx = 0.0; //all components in the row with weightx = 0.0 keeps the components clump together in the center.
                           //This way the labels will be in the center of the panel.

        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START; //FIRST_LINE makes the title and subtitle stay at the top of the frame.
                          //LINE_START make them be glued to the beginning of its column. However because the weightx = 0.0 the column is centered.


        mainPanel.add(titleLabel,  c);
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.weighty = 1.0;  // this weight must be put in the components under the titles so they don't get far from each other.
        mainPanel.add(subtitleLabel, c);


        add(mainPanel);

        setSize(new Dimension(400,300));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: simple code]

I don't like this way a lot because it uses `weightx = 0.0` to keep the labels centered, if you needed to put more GUI elements at the sides you'll need to put the labels in the center column with weightx 0.0 and the elements at each side with weightx >0.0.

For example, replacing the code above with the following we have:

**WAY 2**

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.gridx = 1;
c.gridy = 0;
c.weightx = 0.0;
c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;

mainPanel.add(titleLabel,  c);
c.gridy = 1;
mainPanel.add(subtitleLabel, c);

JPanel colorPanel = new JPanel();
colorPanel.setBackground(Color.red);
colorPanel.setOpaque(true);

JPanel colorPanel2 = new JPanel();
colorPanel2.setBackground(Color.gray);
colorPanel2.setOpaque(true);

c.weighty = 1.0;
c.gridy = 0;
c.gridx = 0;
c.weightx = 1.0;
c.gridheight = 2;
c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
mainPanel.add(colorPanel, c);
c.gridx = 2;
mainPanel.add(colorPanel2, c);

add(mainPanel);
```

Result:

[image: way 2]

**EDIT**

The key to doing good layouts with gridbag layout is understanding how are you creating the grid. Then you just have to play with the weight and the anchor to place the components in each cell.

This is my 2x3 grid, on the SECOND WAY (without the colors).

[image]

This is your 2x1 grid

[image]

With your grid you can't align the beginning of the labels, with my grid you can.

Comment: I'm going to add some comments in the code explaining why the constraints have those values. I've posted it already so you can take a look and try to figure it by yourself.

Comment: hmm Thanks @DSquare but it would be more convinient if u could edit my code..??

Comment: Nope, I can't do that, your code isn't even a proper program, I know nothing about what are you doing. You have to understand how it works and then you'll be able to expand it to implement whatever you want. My code is a very small example so you can see what's important and see how it works. I'm here teaching you things about layouts, not doing your work.

Comment: What is reason for the anchor to be First_line_start ? Why not the anchor is to be changed for the subtitle label..?? Means title shouldn't be page_start and sub should be the First_line_start..??

Comment: I am really poor at Gridbag layout plz someone help me out there or can pose a clear explanation for that..??

Comment: @Gurjit That way works too, it's the first I thought of, however it's equivalent to both having FIRST_LINE_START because you need to have the string of the title touching the beginning of the column anyways (in the second picture, touching the red zone) so that you can put the  subtitle at the beginning of its line and ends up aligned with the beginning of the title.

Comment: Thats what i was asking bro its not working with that your code is working but why so..??

Comment: There are several other key diferences, essentially you need to make the title and the subtitle start at the beginning of its column. With gridBagLayout you have to thing about how are you creating the grid on the GUI. See in the second picture the red zone is the first column, the title-subtitle are in the second column, the key here is that both title and subtitle are touching the red zone. In your code if you put the subtitle at the beginning of the line it will end up at the left of the frame because that's where its column begins.

Comment: I can't make you understand this (or anything) in 1 minute, it's something you have to work, play, test until you get the grasp of it. You spent 5 hours trying to solve this. Well, now have to spend some more time but now you have the advantage of having a couple of solutions instead of trying things in the dark. Read carefully the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html), and try a lot of things in a simple program like the one I did until you understand why my code works and yours not. The key is in understanding how the grid is distributed in the frame.

Comment: hmm,,thanks man,,one thing more if i want to lay down a text area below it having its width more than the column .?? How can I do it..??

Comment: Use `GridBagConstraints.gridwidth` to make a component span through several columns. For example in the second way I'd put the text area in the column 0 and the row 2 (a new row), and put it width `c.gridwidth = 3` so it will occupy the whole screen. You might also want to change the value of `c.fill` look at the tutorial to see the options. And remember to put the `weighty = 1.0` after the subtitle. The subtitle now has to have `weighty = 0.0`. Try it and you'll see why.